# How to remove some of the Swift libraries copied by Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

In Xcode 10, the "Copy Swift standard libraries" script is done last — after any custom build phases that may be added to the target. Hence it is not possible to create a custom build script to specifically **remove** Swift standard `dylib` files added by Xcode.

The question is, how to **remove** some of these standard libraries that are erroneously added by Xcode?

The reason behind it is that when Xcode 10 builds a Swift 4.2 macOS app that has a Photo Editing extension, it adds `libswiftMapKit.dylib` into the application bundle — even when the application does not have Maps functionality or import MapKit.  This caused an App Review rejection.

Comment: It's odd Apple would reject an app based on the results of their IDE. Could it be that your code is causing the MapKit bundling?

Comment: @Cristik - No, since I have a skeleton project that proves it.

Comment: Care to share it with us? So that we don't attempt to guess what's causing the MapKit bundling?

Comment: @Cristik Can. How?

Comment: Github and share the link?

Comment: @Cristik Done – https://github.com/adib/Xcode-10-MapKit-Dependency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180526/discussion-between-adib-and-cristik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a Swift Standard Library, add a *Post-Actions* in the scheme. Most likely this would be an Archive post-action since archiving is typical prior to a release (upload to App Store or to re-sign using a Developer ID credential).

1. In Xcode 10 Click `Edit Scheme`.
2. In the scheme editing, expand the `Archive` section.
3. Click on `Post-Actions`

Enter the following `bash` script fragment (along with any other post-actions that you may already have)

```sh
# This variable points to the `Frameworks` folder of the final application.
full_frameworks_path="${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}/Applications/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}"
# Specify the libraries to remove, the example below removes Swift's MapKit wrapper.
rm -f "${full_frameworks_path}/libswiftMapKit.dylib
```

However note that this does not solve the underlying problem of the Photos App Extension actually links to `libswiftMapKit.dylib` — a dependency added by Xcode 10.0 regardless whether it really uses MapKit or not.